# After my test is executed, I want it to Uninstall the App as well

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium

// I'm running tests on Emulator.

Once my test is executed, I want it to Uninstall the App as well, How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just use "noResetValue" capability while you set them for appium.

it takes value, true , false

when set to false , it uninstalls the app and re-installs each time you re-run your suite
java example:

```
capa = new DesiredCapabilities();    
capa.setCapability("noResetValue","false");
```

Comment: Is there any way except remove_app(*.*.*), as I am looking for uninstall app only once not for each scenario. And for iOS above mentioned code is not working. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

something like this might help you.

```
adb uninstall com.example.android.apis
```

[This](http://appium.io/slate/en/tutorial/android.html?ruby#running-using-jenkins-ci) article might help you.